# Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Tags: c#, linq

I have this beloq query which is giving me an exception.
Now j.job_quote.JobQuoteID  is an identity column which null, thurs trying to create a check if null then identify as 0. Please help why i am getting the issue and what can i do to handle it

```
var Qryjob = (from j in at.jobs 

                     where j.JobID == Convert.ToInt32(jobid)
                     select new {
                         JobID = j.JobID,
                         InsertedDate = j.InsertedDate,
                         FirstName = j.user.FirstName,
                         LastName = j.user.LastName,
                         City = j.user.City,
                         ServiceName = j.service.ServiceName,
                         ServiceTypeName = j.service_type.ServiceTypeName,
                         BudgetName = j.budget.BudgetName,
                         IsApproved = j.IsApproved,
                         IsAssigned = j.IsAssigned,
                         IsQuoted = j.IsQuoted,
                         job_notif_price = j.job_notif_price,
                         Description = j.Description,
                         PaymentTypeName = j.payment_type.PaymentTypeName,
                         DuePeriodName = j.due_period.DuePeriodName,
                         QuoteStatus = j.job_quote.QuoteStatus,
                         JobStatus = j.job_quote.JobStatus,
                         comments = j.job_quote.comments,
                         IsPartnerApply = j.job_quote.IsPartnerApply,
                         Applycomment = j.job_quote.ApplyComments,
                         JobQuoteID = j.job_quote.JobQuoteID ?? 0
                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The variable on the left side of `??` operator has to be nullable (which means that you can assign null to it), in your case `JobQuoteID` should be of type `int?` not `int`

Answer (score 12):

The compiler is telling you that `j.job_quote.JobQuoteID` is of type `int`.  An `int` cannot be null, as it is a non-nullable value type.  The `??` operator cannot be called on a type that is not nullable.

Answer (score 7):

That is the null-coalescing operator, it only applies to nullable types, or rather the left hand side must be a nullable type (my language might be wrong there but when I say nullable i mean all `Nullable<T>`'s and reference types). If you had `int?` instead of `int` it would work. The operator is binary and works like so; `a ?? b` says that if `a` is null then use b for the value. You can chain this as many times as you'd like. So I could do `int willNeverBeNull = a ?? b ?? c ?? 4` assuming a, b, and c are all nullable ints, it will take the first non null value.

Answer (score 1):

As @Servy said issue is not with the `JobQuoteID` instead I think the error is occurring because your `job_quote` object is null, thus the expression should be:

```
JobQuoteID = (j.job_quote ?? new job_quote { JobQuoteID = 0 }).JobQuoteID
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: This is simple and original!